# CQ5 AEM - multifieldpanel doesn't remove node from crx

Tags: aem

I need to create a component (say componentA) whose aim is to allow a user to add a variable number of components (choosing from componentB and componentC). So componentA is like a parsys which contains others components.

I'm using a *[multifieldpanel](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/)* to create a component's dialog with a user controlled number of field. Something like this:
[image]

The problem is when I try to eliminate one of the elements added directly from the dialog of componentA: the element is effectively eliminated from the dialog but it actually remains inside the CRX.
My CRX is something like:

- componentA

  - componentASon_0
  - componentASon_1

If I remove the component (componentASon_0 or componentASon_1) with a "right-click and delete" it works properly.

Any advice?

Here a snippet of the dialog relative to the *componentA*:

```
<tabMain
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    title="myPanelTitle"
                    xtype="panel">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <settings jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                              fieldLabel="Payment Settings"
                              fieldDescription="Click the '+' to add a new block"
                              name="./settings"
                              xtype="multifield">
                        <fieldConfig
                                jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                xtype="multifieldpanel">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                                <component
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        defaultValue="Choose a component"
                                        fieldLabel="Component"
                                        type="select"
                                        value=""
                                        key="componentType"
                                        xtype="selection">
                                    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                        <componentB
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                text="ComponentB"
                                                value="/apps/project/components/commons/componentB"/>
                                        <componentC
                                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                text="ComponentC"
                                                value="/apps/project/components/commons/componentC"/>
                                    </options>
                                </component>
                            </items>
                        </fieldConfig>
                    </settings>
                </items>
            </tabMain>
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to put up a snippet of dialog and multifield codes, it would make it easier for us here to help you out.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to write a listener that deletes the respective component from under the :jcr content node of the page. This listener will have to be called when you click the red "delete" icon, which means you perhaps need to extend the default multifield.js provided.

not sure if there is an easier workaround, sorry

Comment: Can I ask that you create a bug report at http://github.com/adobe-consulting-services/acs-aem-commons/ ?